# Starting Java Agent on Java Applet (jp2launcher)

Tags: java, javaagents, jvmti, java-attach-api

I want to start a Java agent on a Java applet running on jp2launcher. I manage to attach to jp2launcher.exe using this [jattach](https://github.com/apangin/jattach) tool and I can inspect that my agent .jar file gets loaded, but neither my preMain or agentMain gets called.

The same behavior occurs when I attach to the process using com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine to attach to jp2launcher.exe and load the agent this way.

I have successfully used the above methods to start an agent on normal Java apps.

Any ideas why this happens and if it is possible to start a Java agent on an applet?

---

Edit:

It seems to be a security issue that causes agent load to fail. Haven't managed yet to load the agent neither by using jattach or tools.attach, but did that by using the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS environment variable.

```
setx JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS "-javaagent:agent.jar -Djava.security.policy=file.policy"
```

with `file.policy` containing:

```
grant {
permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

Comment: How do you determine that the jar file got loaded and/or that the agentMain method has not been called?

Comment: i use ProcessHacker https://processhacker.sourceforge.io/ to look at the handles of jp2launcher, and I can see my agent jar file. I log on the first line of my agentmain and no logs are created.